# How to pass Workflow service exception to client

Tags: asp.net, wcf, workflow-foundation-4

I am using a WCF Workflow service application (DeclarativeServiceLibrary). I have a Windows Forms client talking to the workflow service. I am able to handle known errors using TryCatch blocks. 
But in case the program meets any unknown exception and comes to the catch block, I want to return a Generic message to the client. Could anybody help me in achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a sample that demonstrates this for WCF Services and WorkflowServices check it out.

- [WCF / WF Service Fault and Validation Example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WCF-WF-Service-Fault-and-e4b6713f)

Answer (score 0):

If the exception is caught within the workflow, then you should use a SendReply activity that provides the fault exception. Your service contract also needs to define the fault contract otherwise the exception received on the client will fault the channel.